# In Perl, how can find the smallest value in a list and keeping the index corresponding to that value?

Tags: perl, max, min

I am looking to distinguish the difference between side_i and side_j to find the smallest value ... following on... to then multiply the smallest and largest by a given number.

That's pretty simple to do. However, I want to still be able to distinguish between i and j in such a way that I know which one is which after they have been multiplied.

This is what I have so far. Please note , I am a very new user of Perl and general coding:

```
use strict; 
use Getopt::Long;
use List::Util qw(max);
use File::Find;
use warnings 'all';



my $side_i = 24.56; 
my $side_j = 3.56; 
my $maxi = 10;
my $maxj = 10; 
my $threshold = 0.05; 
my $small_side;



(my $sside, my $bside) = smallestTest($side_i, $side_j);


sub smallestTest{

    my $sside;
    my $bside;
    print "$_[0] $_[1] /n";
    if ($_[0]<$_[1]){
        $sside = $_[0];
        $bside = $_[1];
    } else {
        $sside = $_[1];
        $bside = $_[0];
    }
return($sside, $bside);
}
print "Biggest side is $bside /n";

my $newSide_i = $.....*20;
my $newSide_j = $.....*21;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that you use a hash `%side` to contain the values. Then the `$sside` and `$bside` variables can hold the identities `i` and `j` of the smallest and biggest values

You don't explain what you want to do after you've determined which is which, so my multiplications at the end are probably way off

```
use strict; 
use warnings 'all';

my %side = ( i => 24.56, j => 3.56 );

my ($sside, $bside) = $side{i} < $side{j} ? qw/ i j / : qw/ j i /;

$side{$sside} *= 20;
$side{$bside} *= 21;
```

If you prefer, you could use `sort` instead to order the hash keys. The result is identical

```
my ($sside, $bside) = sort { $side{$a} <=> $side{$b} } keys %side;
```

Comment: 35 points to go and it's already displaying 100k. You've got a mug coming your way soon! :)

Comment: I was hoping to be able to re-use this Function, hence why i've put it in a sub.  I am going to go and read about %hash first and come back to this . Thank you for your suggestion so far !

Comment: @simbabque: Is that still a thing?

Comment: They will send you an email asking for shipping details. There is a 100k package with a tshirt and some stuff. Choroba got it recently too. There might be a photo from YAPC in cluj of both of us wearing it together.

Comment: @simbabque: Cool! I hadn't heard of anyone getting a mug for a very long time so I assumed it had lapsed. How come you know all this, and how come you have a shirt?!

Comment: Actually I don't know if you will get a mug. I do know about the tshirt from metal posts. I got my stuff from the 10M questions meta post. I actually have two shirts. I got one for my answer and one for someone writing how helpful I was, but I have not found that post yet. The first package had a mug. And recently they shipped a signed book by Joel express to Germany because they had run out when they sent the orogon original packages.

Comment: @Borodin Congrats :)))

Comment: Clumsy fingers and rain ☔ congratulations

Comment: @simbabque: Thanks man. You really shouldn't post in the rain! Where are you? And did you really post 10M questions on Meta? That deserves more than a T shirt!

Comment: Haha, no. I wrote [this answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303313/1331451) to one of the 10 Million Questions meta posts. And somewhere in that thread there is another answer about me I guess. I was going home. Weather in Berlin was horrible today.

Comment: @simbabque: I'm sorry, I'm sure I knew that you were German. It's your impeccable English that makes me forget! I know that I have been irascible this last year and I am ashamed of many of my posts. Things will change dramatically very soon, and my contributions will either vanish altogether or be much more considerate. Thank you for your patience with me.

Answer (score 1):

In math, what you are referring to are called [argmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max) and [argmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max#Arg_min). You can get their functionality in various ways.

First, given a list of values, you can find their maximum and minimum, and then select the indices which correspond to elements of the list with the maximum and minimum values, respectively. This is implemented in the `using_only_max_min` function below. Note that this method makes two passes over the array for each extremum: Once to find the extremum and another time to find the corresponding indices.

Or, given a list of values, you can find the indices which corresponding to the extrema in the list, and then select the corresponding value for any of them to get the value of the extremum. This is implemented in the `using_by_functions` routine below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use List::AllUtils qw(max min max_by min_by);

my @n = (1, 3, 5, 8, 8, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6);

print Dumper using_only_max_min(\@n);
print Dumper using_by_functions(\@n);

sub using_only_max_min {
    my $n = shift;

    my $max = max @$n;
    my @argmax = grep $n->[$_] == $max, 0 .. $#$n;

    my $min = min @$n;
    my @argmin = grep $n->[$_] == $min, 0 .. $#$n;

    return {
        max => $max,
        argmax => \@argmax,
        min => $min,
        argmin => \@argmin,
    };
}

sub using_by_functions {
    my $n = shift;

    my @argmax = max_by { $n->[$_] } 0 .. $#$n;
    my $max = $n->[$argmax[0]];

    my @argmin = min_by { $n->[$_] } 0 .. $#$n;
    my $min = $n->[$argmin[0]];

    return {
        max => $max,
        argmax => \@argmax,
        min => $min,
        argmin => \@argmin,
    };
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'argmin' => [
                        0
                      ],
          'max' => 8,
          'min' => 1,
          'argmax' => [
                        3,
                        4
                      ]
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'argmax' => [
                        3,
                        4
                      ],
          'min' => 1,
          'max' => 8,
          'argmin' => [
                        0
                      ]
        };
```

You can also do this without using any libraries, and find the two extrema in one go. The function below returns a hash reference which contains two entries, `max` and `min`. Each of those point to a list whose first value is the value of the extremum, and the second value is the list of indices corresponding to the extremum:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @n = (1, 3, 5, 8, 8, 3, 2, 4, 4, 6);

print Dumper find_extrema(\@n, sub { $_[0] <=> $_[1]});

sub find_extrema {
    my ($n, $cmp) = @_;

    my ($max, $min) = ([$n->[0], [0]], [$n->[0], [0]]);

    for my $i (1 .. $#$n) {
        my $v = $n->[$i];

        my $r = $cmp->($v, $max->[0]);
        if ($r >= 0) {
            $r ? $max = [$v, [$i]] : push @{ $max->[-1] }, $i;
            next;
        }

        my $s = $cmp->($v, $min->[0]);
        if ($s <= 0) {
            $s ? $min = [$v, [$i]] : push @{ $min->[-1] }, $i;
        }
    }

    return {
        max => $max,
        min => $min,
    };
}
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'min' => [
                     1,
                     [
                       0
                     ]
                   ],
          'max' => [
                     8,
                     [
                       3,
                       4
                     ]
                   ]
        };
```